# Any other shorter way to solve this problem through recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Suppose you have a string made up of only 'a' and 'b'. Write a recursive function that checks if the string was generated using the following rules:
1. The string begins with an 'a'
2. Each 'a' is followed by nothing or an 'a' or "bb"
3. Each "bb" is followed by nothing or an 'a'
If all the rules are followed by the given string, return true otherwise return false.

```
public class temp {

    public static boolean checkAB(String input) {
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            if (input.charAt(0) == 'a')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }


        Boolean ans = checkAB(input.substring(0, input.length() - 1));
        if (ans == false)
            return ans;
        else {
            if (input.charAt(input.length() - 2) == 'a') {
                if (input.charAt(input.length() - 1) == 'a' || input.charAt(input.length() - 1) == 'b')
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if (input.charAt(input.length() - 2) == 'b') {
                if (input.charAt(input.length() - 3) == 'a') {
                    if (input.charAt(input.length() - 1) == 'b') {
                        return true;

                    } else
                        return false;
                }
                if (input.charAt(input.length() - 3) == 'b') {
                    if (input.charAt(input.length() - 1) == 'a') {
                        return true;

                    } else
                        return false;
                }


            } else
                return false;


        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(checkAB("abbbabaaa"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it really need recursion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this pattern: "a+(bba+)*(bb)?"

```
public class ABB
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String arg : args)
            checkAB(arg) ;
    }

    static void checkAB(String s)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s -> %b\n", s, s.matches("a+(bba+)*(bb)?")) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please invest more time in formulating good quality answer. See [answer]. At least, show some minimal Java code of how to use it and explain what it actually is. OP might never have heard of what regex is.

Comment: @Zabuza You're right: the OP might never heard of regex. That's why I posted a comment, encouraging him to dive into the regex ocean and learn to swim himself.

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to tell you that if you invest more time in increasing the quality of your answers, you will get much more up-votes. Now its better, have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 public boolean isValid(String str) {
    if (str.startsWith("a")) {
        final String substring = str.substring(1);
        return (substring.startsWith("a") || substring.startsWith("bb")) ? isValid(substring) : substring.isEmpty();

    } else if (str.startsWith("bb")) {
        final String substring = str.substring(2);
        return (substring.startsWith("a")) ? isValid(substring) : substring.isEmpty();

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```